# Storing data of unknown size in C++

Tags: c++, variables, curl, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been using PHP for about 4 years, however I've come across a problem that requires something with slightly (:P) better performance and so I've chosen C++.

The program I'm writing is a Linux daemon that will scan a MySQL database for URLs to load, load them using cURL, search for a specified string, and then update the database accordingly. The problem that I'm facing is that I don't know the size of the data that needs to be stored in a variable in order to be searched for a specific string.

I had the idea of using a linked list and allocating more nodes as the data fills the list. Is this a good way to go about doing things?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in c++ the vector class can store an unknown sized amount of data.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector <std::string>Data;

std::string newData = "a String";
Data.push_back(newData);

std::string otherData = "a different String";
Data.push_back(otherData);
```

of course 'string' could be any data type you want, and you can access the data using the Data[0] to return the first string, and you can use Data.size() to return the amount of strings in the vector/array.

```
for(int x = 0; x != Data.size(); x++)
{
   //Do what you want with the data here using Data[x]
}
```

Comment: You need to use fully-qualified names or `using namespace std;`

Comment: You would be better off using iteration (with const_iterator), it's more resilient to change in favor of another container.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you would want to use one of the standard containers. My personal suggestion is `std::vector`. YOu can use it as an array (as the data is guaranteed to be contiguous) and it has convenient indexing and insertion operations (seems like you aren't interested in removal at this point).

Specifically, you could set up something like

```
std::vector<char> buff;
// while you are reading data
buff.push_back (item);
```

When you are done you can call `buff.size` to find out how much you read.

As an added bonus (if you are in fact dealing with character buffers), when you finally get all the data you need you can convert to a `std::string` to do whatever searching you want to do.

```
std::vector<char> buff;
buff.push_back('e');
buff.push_back('a');
buff.push_back('t');

std::string s(&buff[0], buff.size());
```

Edited for correctness.

Comment: For the string conversion, do not forget to push a '\0'!

Comment: In the second snippet it will output 'eat' only if you get lucky. C-style strings, which the vector holds, need to be null-terminated.

Comment: @Raphael: or you could use the string contructor which takes both a char * and a size. Something like: `std::string s(&buff[0], buff.size());`

Comment: Right, it will also fail when null characters appear in the stream itself. Providing a size in the constructor helps this, but does not eliminate the problem. I'll update to be explicit.

Comment: -1 This answer has the nice suggestion of using std::vector and then it goes so wrong when going back to a std::string!!! It would be simpler constructing with `std::string s( v.begin(), v.end() )`, there is no need to push a null character at the end and the string will take as many characters as there are in the buffer (both with the iterator or the `const char*`, size constructors) regardless of whether there is a null (0) character in the middle of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a whole lot to discover there.

You should specifically orient your discovery to the STL: use [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)

Now you should try to learn how to use:

- `std::vector`
- `std::string`
- `std::cin` and `std::cout` (globals)

On `std::string` you should note a good number of algorithm like `find`, `find_first_of`, `find_last_of`.

Note that string manipulations in C++ can be quite challenging (as in verbose).

If you are comfortable with regular expressions, you might be willing to try [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html). Note that you have to link with its library.

Also, if you come from PHP and want to increase your performance, you could begin with a lot of different scripting languages (Python is my favorite), and it would probably be easier.

Comment: C/C++ is something I've always wanted to learn more about so I thought I might as well just jump in the deep end and write an app. I've never really been able to like Python that much. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Good luck then, I personally have fun with the language :)